# Use Java 7 Kafka client to communicate with remote Kafka broker running Java 8

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Can we access Kafka installed on other machine using java7 in our system?
I have to fetch the topics by writing a consumer code but i have java7 in my system.
I know for installation we require minimum of java8.

Comment: Are you in linux or windows?

Comment: I am in Windows

Comment: Please update your question to include what happened when you ran any consumer code with Java 7

Comment: I think "?" is missing at the end of your sentence: Can we access Kafka installed on other machine using java7 in our system. If I understood, kafka needs java 8 but you have java 7 in your system?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i am trying to find out if its possible or not cause as i am gathering the requirements first.I still haven't tried to connect as i just know that other machine has kafka

Comment: I suggest you try it. It'll take you less than an hour to test. Stackoverflow shouldn't be for requirements gathering.

Comment: @OneCricketeer i asked it like a general concept.

Comment: AFAIK, Java 7 and 8 have no difference in TCP networking libraries or serialization techniques. As the answer below states, you just need to use dependencies that are compiled to Java 7, or clone Kafka source code and try to compile client libraries yourself

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't upgrade to Java 11 (or at least Java 8)?

Java 7 is totally unsupported and may contain unfixed security vulnerabilities.

If you still can't upgrade to at least Java 8, you will need to use a version of Kafka Clients that was compiled with Java 7. The latest such version was 1.1.1, available from the following Maven Central location:

```
'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.1.1'
```

This is an old version of Kafka Client that will be unable to take advantage of the latest features of Kafka.

Comment: I can't upgrade as my organisation  is not allowing it.

Comment: @Ashish Then how are they allowing Kafka servers to use Java 8, then? And does your company therefore maintain their own patch process for Java 7?